# Xmlhttp request is raising an Access Denied error

Tags: vba, xmlhttprequest

The following Excel macro, which is making an xmlhttp request to this webpage to retrieve some values at a second stage, has worked normally in VBA until some time ago:

```
Sub WebReq()

Link = "http://it.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^FCHI&ql=10" & str(rnd())
Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")

Set RequestWeb = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
With RequestWeb
    .Open "GET", "" & Link & "", False
    .send
    htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
End With

End Sub
```

Now, instead, at the call of the method:

```
    .send
```

of the object msxml2.xmlhttp is raising the following error:

```
Run-time error '-2147024891 (80070005)'
Access is denied.
```

I've been looking on the web but all the similar threads are never answered. Can anyone explain me what this error means, and if there's any way I could fix it or even just work around it?

**Note**: the random string at the end of the variable 'Link' has been added to force the page reloading, since the script is retrieving real-time values and so it should be loaded every time.

**Additional information**: while looking for a solution, I'm noticing now that the random part of the link is yielding always the same value even when I end the running and restart again:

```
Link = http://it.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^FCHI&ql=10 .7055475
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't `rnd()` yield a new random value between 0 and 1 at every call?

Answer (score 31):

Use

```
CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
```

The standard request fired from a local machine forbids access to sites that aren't trusted by IE. `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` is the *server-side* object, that doesn't perform those checks.

Answer (score 10):

i found that, in my case, changing http to https fixed the access denied problem.  i can only assume that the website somehow made a change and didn't tell anyone

Comment: Such a simple solution! Same thing happened to me!

Comment: After wasting time changing my headers it turned out this was my solution as well.

Answer (score 6):

access denied is IE issue

```
internet options > security tab > custom security level > Miscellaneous >Access data sources across domains > enable
```

Comment: Interesting. This was my issue in IE6; even though the post was going to a sub-domain of the page's domain, IE6 wouldn't allow the sub-domain by default. Ultimately, instead of using a sub-domain, I had to just use a different port number than 80 on the same domain (along with a port-forwarder in the firewall so I could get the resource actually located on a different server internally).

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

```
Sub WebReq()

link = "http://it.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^FCHI&ql=10" & Str(Rnd())
Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")
Dim objHttp

    Set objHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHttp.Open "GET", link, False

    objHttp.Send
    htm.body.innerhtml = objHttp.responsetext
    Set objHttp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, at debug time the `3.0` object doesn't raise the `access denied` error but it returns an empty `responseText`. Instead, at run-time it fails with a `The data is not available yet` :/

Comment: @MatteoNNZ My bad matteo, try out the above code instead, I returned HTML this time and it was successful.

Comment: maybe something is against me but now I get `Run-time error '-2147012889 (80072ee7): The server name or address could not be resolved`. I have been lookinf for a bit on the web, it seems is something related to the browser proxy.. I confess I'm not much of an expert about web services, do you have idea why this object raises this problem?

Comment: Well if there is a limitation built into your company browser proxy package for accessing html via vbscript that could definitely cause it. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't think so, I've thought the same at some point but some friends tried the code under my request and were getting the same error so I don't think it depends on the network.

Comment: That's strange, as i'm using this exact same script to send me updates from www.slashdot.org upon new entries.

Comment: Yes, but indeed what I mean is not the script does not work, but the website of Yahoo! Finance is not returning the request. I'm sure it works  on other websites, I'm using it myself for other purposes. Well, I guess that just got tired of this, I don't know, but I fixed the problem by finding another data provider online. Thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
  .Open "GET", URL, False
  .Send
  content = .ResponseText
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the user didn't have AD permissions to the proxy server on our corporate network. (Simple oversight when setting up the user.) Adding the missing security group fixed the problem for the user.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by changing the link being passed from being "http://" to "https://"

The site I was pulling had upgraded and trying to pull the data using the unsecured link was failing.  Works great now (no code change required.

Answer (score 0):

add "www" after "https://" in your custom Link, 
Like this:

```
XMLPage.Open "GET", "https://www.x-rates.com/table/?from=GBP&amount=3", False    
XMLPage.send
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid I don't understand exactly why this problem occurs, but I'm guessing it is the secure "https://" versus insecure "http://".  I ran into the same "access denied" message while following sample code from a VBA course.  The original code was:

```
XMLPage.Open "GET", "http://x-rates.com/table/?from=GBP&amount=3", False    
XMLPage.send
```

I changed the "http://" to "https://" and the error went away.