# Access Denied error on GETHTML function

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some data from a site, and I'm getting this error on the main search page:

> Access Denied (run-time error -2147024891 (80070005) error on .send in GETHTML() function.

Here is my code:

```vb
Function GetHTML(URL As String) As String
    Dim HTML As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        GetHTML = .responseText
    End With
End Function

Function GetNumberofPages(numpage As String)

    Dim oHtml       As HTMLDocument
    Dim oElement    As Object
    Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument
    Dim maintext2 As String


    gr = ""

    'maintext2 = "http://www.simplycigars.co.uk/advanced_search_result.php?search_in_description=1&inc_subcat=1&pfrom=0&pto=10000&sort=2a&display=all"
    Text = GetHTML(maintxt)
    With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", maintxt & gr, False
        .send
        oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    aa = InStr(1, Text, "Displaying")

    nmpage = Val(Mid(Text, aa + 66, 5))
    GetNumberofPages = nmpage

End Function
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xmlhttp request is raising an Access Denied error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938194/xmlhttp-request-is-raising-an-access-denied-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this answer...

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36292949/3043

... you need the `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0` object instead of `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`. You already have sample code in here that uses 5.1; that might work, too.

Changing the object did work for me. However, I tested with VBScript instead of VBA. Also, that code is a string mix of .Net and classic VB. When testing in VBScript, I had to use this function:

```
Function GetHTML(URL)    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        GetHTML = .responseText
    End With
End Function
```

Finally, it's rarely a good idea to scrape HTML like this. Instead, look for an rss feed or api you can use, even if it means tracking through the HTML to find the JSON data used to populate a page.

This will make your program more resilient against design changes by the site, run faster, and use less bandwidth and resources for the site owners. Sometimes these things will not exist, and that may be the case here, but it's worth repeating often.