# Send SMS from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have code for my Excel application. It's a membership loyalty program and every time members are billed it will send the current billed amount along with points earned or redeemed.

I have purchased a bulk SMS account and they have provide me the API. I need to use this API in my code.

Below is the API provided by my bulk SMS provider.

```
https://malert.in/api/api_http.php?username=user&password=pwd&senderid=myid&to=9000000000&text=Hello%20world&route=Enterprise&type=text&datetime=2018-02-22%2012%3A54%3A22
```

Comment: I think you just want to use `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="http://example.microsoft.com"` Just setup the `Address` string using whatever you want to use - so, something like `ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:="https://malert.in/api/api_http.php?username=user&password=pwd&senderid=myid&to=9000000000& text=Hello%20world&route=Enterprise&type=text&datetime=2018-02-22%2012%3A54%3A22"`

Comment: You can also do something like this maybe? if you don't want to popup a window `Sub WebReq()

link = "https://malert.in/api/api_http.php?username=user&password=pwd&senderid=myid&to=9000000000& text=Hello%20world&route=Enterprise&type=text&datetime=2018-02-22%2012%3A54%3A22"
Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")
Dim objHttp

    Set objHttp = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHttp.Open "GET", link, False

    objHttp.Send
    Debug.Print objHttp.responsetext
    Set objHttp = Nothing
End Sub`

Comment: Read more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22938837/1274820

Comment: People charge for sending SMS? Don't you have an email account?

Comment: Jeeped one issue with emails is you have to know their carrier - I suppose it's possible to discover, but it's an issue.

Comment: Ah! So you get charged 'cause you cannot xmlhttp the carrier from the web. I suppose that is expedient for some.

Comment: @Jeeped Charging for SMS used to be the norm in the 90s and 2000s when SMS was new. These days most carriers provide it for free because the cost of transmitting and receiving SMS messages is like $0.0001.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your SMS provide using a https get request, then here is example.

```
Sub Test_SMS()

'  //this should work with if winhttp.dll existing in system32 dir. 
'  Dim HttpReq  As New WinHttpRequest


Dim response As String
Dim sURL As String

' //another way to create the HttpReq
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

' // build your string
sURL = "https://malert.in/api/api_http.php?username=user&password=pwd&senderid=myid&to=9000000000& text=Hello%20world&route=Enterprise&type=text&datetime=2018-02-22%2012%3A54%3A22"

On Error Resume Next

With HttpReq
.Open "GET", sURL, False
.Send
End With

response = HttpReq.responseText
HttpReq.WaitForResponse
Debug.Print response

End Sub
```

Comment: which reference to add

Comment: don't understand your question, this code using the winhttp.dll located in windows/system32.

Comment: Nothing happend, code works without error but no sms received.

Comment: please first test the url using  ie/chrome,  Just put your URL in the chrome, and check if the SMS received. Another method is using postman with chrome to testing this url..

Comment: The code is nothing else but just using https  get method to send the url, so you need first test your url is correct, especially the token(username/password) .....

Comment: I have checked it and it was successful but from the program i got no sms.

Comment: Are you able to get the response from the code?  "Debug.Print response", what is the response for this?

Comment: No, I didn't but I checked it using step by step and it execute all lines to the end.

Comment: Option Explicit
Sub sendsms()
On Error GoTo Err_sendSMS
Dim strResult As String
Dim URL_base As String
Dim str_POST As String
Dim HttpReq  As New XMLHTTP
Set HttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
 str_POST = "https://malert.in/api/api_http.php?username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx&senderid=REDHCP&to=917980580867&text=new&route=Enterprise&type=text"
Debug.Print str_POST
HttpReq.Open "GET", str_POST, False
HttpReq.Send
MsgBox HttpReq.ResponseText
Exit_sendSMS:
    Exit Sub
Err_sendSMS:
    MsgBox "sendSMS - " & Err.Description & " " & Err.Number
    Resume Exit_sendSMS
End Sub

Comment: getting an error "the system cannot locate the resource speicified. -2146697211

Comment: Sorry my api password contains @ which creates the problem. Thanks it's a great help.

Comment: can you help me on this I just used to variable which replaces "to" and "text". but got an error msg

Comment: ERROR type value This a test Messege does not match regexp /^(text|unicode|flash|wap_push|vcard|picture)$/

Comment: sURL = "https://malert.in/api/api_http.php?username=xxxxx&password=xxxxx&senderid=REDHCP&to=" & sms_to & "&text=Deb&route=Enterprise&type=" & sms_text

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figure it out and it's working. below is the code

```
Sub send_SMS(xyz As Integer)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'   Declaring varibles for sending sms

    Dim HttpReq  As New WinHttpRequest
    Dim response As String
    Dim sURL As String
    Dim smsto, smstext As String
'   Declaring varibles for Application

    Dim lastrow, lastrow1, lastrow2, x, pointe As Long
    lastrow = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow1 = Sheets(2).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = Sheets(3).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'   Caculation of red card points

    If xyz = 1 Then
        pointe = (frmmain.txtpointe.Value - frmmain.txtpointr.Value) + (frmmain.txtamount.Value * 10 / 100)
        smstext = "Dear Member, You have reedemed " & frmmain.txtpointr.Text & " red points and your balance is " & pointe & " points"
    Else
        pointe = frmmain.txtpointe.Value + (frmmain.txtamount.Value * 10 / 100)
        If pointe >= 1000 Then

            smstext = "Dear Member, You have reached " & pointe & " red points and you can reedem it your next visit"
        Else

            smstext = "Dear Member, Your bill amount is " & frmmain.txtinvoice.Text & " and your Red Point balance is " & pointe & " Points"
        End If
    End If
'  Checking for valid mobile number

    If Len(frmmain.lblmobile.Caption) < 10 Then


      Call nomobile(pointe)

    Else
        smsto = CStr(frmmain.lblmobile.Caption)

        ' //another way to create the HttpReq
        Set HttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

        ' // API for sending sms
        sURL = "https://malert.in/api/api_http.php?username=username&password=password&senderid=REDHCP&to=" & smsto & "&text=" & smstext & "&route=Enterprise&type=text"
    '    Debug.Print sURL
        On Error Resume Next

        With HttpReq
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        End With

        response = HttpReq.responseText
        HttpReq.waitForResponse
'        MsgBox Left(response, 2)
        Debug.Print response

            If Left(response, 2) = "OK" Then
                Call nomobile(pointe)
            Else
               Call errorconnection(smstext, pointe)
            End If
    End If
    sURL = "https://malert.in/api/api_http_balance.php?username=username&password=password&route=Enterprise"
    '    Debug.Print sURL
        On Error Resume Next

        With HttpReq
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .send
        End With

        response = HttpReq.responseText
        HttpReq.waitForResponse
        frmmain.lblstatus.Caption = response
        Debug.Print response
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```