# Download picture through xmlhttp

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get the src attribute of pictures on a page, then to download that picture and here's my code

```
picURL = "https://iofferman.x.yupoo.com/33269655?uid=1"

Set htmlPic = GetHTML(picURL)
Debug.Print Replace(htmlPic.querySelector(".viewer__imgwrap img").getAttribute("src"), "about:", "https:")
Dim myPic As String
myPic = Replace(htmlPic.querySelector(".viewer__imgwrap img").getAttribute("src"), "about:", "https:")
'URLDownloadToFile 0, myPic, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & picID & ".jpg", 0, 0
Call SaveWebFile(myPic, ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & picID & ".jpg")
```

This is related to code

```
Function GetHTML(ByVal sURL As String) As HTMLDocument
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    With http
        .Open "Get", sURL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    Set GetHTML = html
End Function
```

and this is the UDF for downloading the picture

```
Function SaveWebFile(ByVal sFile$, ByVal sPath$) As Boolean
    Dim f&, oResp() As Byte
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sFile, False
        .send
        Do While (.readyState <> 4): DoEvents: Loop
        oResp = .responseBody
    End With
    f = FreeFile
    If Dir(sPath) <> "" Then Kill sPath
    Open sPath For Binary As #f
    Put #f, , oResp
    Close #f
End Function
```

I could get the link for the picture, for example: `https://photo.yupoo.com/iofferman/2d03c9b8/326e8e47.jpg` but when navigating to it, I sometimes could get the picture correctly and sometimes gives me incorrect output like that `http://adc.yupoo.com/res/703.gif`. How can I download the picture correctly?

Comment: I had to delete my answer. The link `https://iofferman.x.yupoo.com/33269655?uid=1` is not an image link. It is a webpage link. If you check the source of the webpage, you will see the actual link of the image is `"//photo.yupoo.com/iofferman/2d03c9b8/326e8e47.jpg"` You can see that in the source of the page `<a id="viewer__origin_img" target="_blank" class="button small onlydesktop" href="//photo.yupoo.com/iofferman/2d03c9b8/326e8e47.jpg">Original image</a>` You need to look for the anchor text `Original image` and then extract the link from there

Comment: This is the problem. When you take out this link and try to see the image (sometimes work and sometimes give me another picture which is considered incorrect)

Comment: You need to look for the anchor text `Original image` and then extract the link from there. That ways you will always get the right link

Comment: What anchor text? Can you extract the link for this picture to try it? Isn't the correct link `https//photo.yupoo.com/iofferman/2d03c9b8/326e8e47.jpg`?

Comment: `Isn't the correct link https//photo.yupoo.com/iofferman/2d03c9b8/326e8e47.jpg` Yes it is. That is what I mentioned in the 1st comment that I posted above. Open the link `https://iofferman.x.yupoo.com/33269655?uid=1` in a browser and then right click on it and click on `View Source`. There you can see the source of the webpage. Search for the text `Original image`. There you can see the actual link. If you can give couple of links, I can suggest a code to extract the link from it

Comment: When I navigate to the picture link I got incorrect picture `http://adc.yupoo.com/res/703.gif` ..

Comment: When i navigated to `photo.yupoo.com/iofferman/2d03c9b8/326e8e47.jpg`, I got the correct picture

Comment: Can you try to open a new tab and paste the picture link again,please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217512/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-yasserkhalil).

Answer (score 3):

You can download the pictures via an ADODB.Stream:

```
Sub DownloadFile(ImageURL, SavePath)

    Dim WinHttpReq As Object

    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", ImageURL, False
    WinHttpReq.send
    
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set MyStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        MyStream.Open
        MyStream.Type = 1
        MyStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        MyStream.SaveToFile SavePath, 2 ' 1: Don't overwrite, 2: Overwrite
        MyStream.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got access denied at this line `winHttpReq.send`

Comment: Add access credentials like this this: `WinHttpReq.Open "GET", ImageURL, False, "username", "password"`

Comment: I still get Access denied even after credential input.

Comment: There is a thread dedicated to the access denied issue here: [Xmlhttp request is raising an Access Denied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938194/xmlhttp-request-is-raising-an-access-denied-error). One possible solution is to use `Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") ` instead. Read the posts at the link for background.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The `WinHttpReq.Status` equals to 302

Comment: I tried this and no errors `Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")`. The downloaded picture is not the expected one (this is the main problem in fact)

Comment: `http://adc.yupoo.com/res/703.gif` is a small GIF with text in Chinese, which I can't read. But the file name "703" may be a clue that this is a 703 error message, "Remote Access Error." My guess is that there is a server redirect going on, possibly because the expected image is unavailable. This is a server issue, not a VBA issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems the problem. Is there any workaround to bypass the problem?

Comment: Not if the image is unavailable.

Comment: But all the images are available at this link `https://iofferman.x.yupoo.com/33269655?uid=1`. Is there any API alternative solution for saving the images?

Comment: If it is a server redirect, it could be intentional to prevent scripts from scraping images. Apparently a 703 error can also be caused by a firewall or AV, or it could be an issue of access credentials -- basically anything that interferes with your ability to access the resource. If you want to dig deeper into that issue, you should post a new question with that as the topic.

Comment: ... Because I don't know anything about it, and people who do are never going to see your question buried in the comments here.